# OWASP ZAP python API error running script

Tags: python, api, compiler-errors, zap

i want to use python-owasp-zap api. I downloaded and installed all the repositories required for python-owasp-zap . when i run a sample code which was given in the web site https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/ApiPython I am getting the below error, please help me .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zap2.py", line 34, in <module>
    while (int(zap.spider.status()) < 100):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Does Not Exist'
```

Then, i tried removing paranthesis from status method:

```
while (int(zap.spider.status) < 100):
     print 'Spider progress %: ' + zap.spider.status
     time.sleep(2)
```

And i get the following error:

```
TypeError: Int argument must be an Int or string not an InstanceMethod
```

Help on rectifying the error is most appreciated.

Comment: it says `zap.spider.status()` is returning `Does Not Exist`. you need to figure out why it's doing that instead of returning a decimal

Comment: i messed with my owasp zap api installation and now i get `IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
while (int(zap.spider.status()) < 100):
    print 'Spider progress %: ' + zap.spider.status()
    time.sleep(5)
```

We have an example script here which we use for scanning wavsep: https://github.com/zapbot/zap-mgmt-scripts/blob/master/wavsep/wavsep-1.5-spider-scan.py

I'll update the ZAP wiki asap ;)

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Answer (score 0):

Spider.status() takes a parameter, scanid. This is to keep track of different scans. You need to specify which scan this is and can be done as shown below.

```
target = 'some decimal base address'
scanid = zap.spider.scan(target)
while (int(zap.spider.status(scanid)) < 100):
    print 'Spider progress %: ' + zap.spider.status(scanid)
    time.sleep(5)
```